# replaceWith() not working on some mobile phones

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm setting up a Wordpress theme for a client and I'm trying to replace the Logo on smaller screens / mobile phones. This jquery script works on desktop when resized / refreshed as well as some mobile phones (Nokia and LG Optimus) however in iPhones, Samsung Galaxy, Google Nexus and Blackberry phones the logo is not replaced with the smaller version.

Below is the code I'm using, this is added through the theme's "custom code" form and is added in the footer. *(Unfortunately I'm not able to enqueue a script in the child theme to add this snippet for some mysterious reason)*.

I'm at a loss as to how to resolve this problem, any help would be appreciated.

```
<script>
(function($){
    var width = $(window).width(),
        defaultLogo = $('.default-logo'),
            mobileLogo = $('<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/small-logo.png" alt="" class="default-logo">');

    if(width <= 530) {
        defaultLogo.replaceWith(mobileLogo);        
    }

 })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(function ($) {
  /**
   * ===============================================
   * Cross-browser polyfill
   * @returns {Number|number} - Browser width (px)
   * ===============================================
   */
  function getBrowserWidth() {
    return window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
  }

  function swapLogo() {
    var $logo = $('img.default-logo');
    if ($logo.length) {
      if (getBrowserWidth() < 530) {
        $logo.prop('src', '/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/small-logo.png');
      } else {
        $logo.prop('src', '/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/large-logo.png'); // replace with actual image name
      }
    }
  }

  $(function () {
    swapLogo();
    $(window).resize(swapLogo);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Tomanow, unfortunately the problem still remains. Although with this script none of the mobile phones work.

Comment: Sorry I added an extra `$` at the beginning by mistake. It is now removed.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate you taking the time to help me solve this problem. I tried the updated script and it is working similarly to what I originally wrote, it seems it works on desktop screens when resized and some mobile phones. However when I look at the site with Chrome's responsive emulators the logo still doesn't change in iPhone, Galaxy or Blackberry phones. I just don't get it. I'm wondering if it's some problem with how iOS and Android are handling jQuery. 

This is my dev site so you can see what I mean:
http://summerink.lostdoggrafix.com/

Comment: Well as it turns out the problem was that this theme was loading a separate logo on high resolution screens, so that is why the larger logo was loading on those other phones. I adjusted the script to replace the retina display logos as well as the default logos and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved, the problem was that the theme was loading a separate logo image on retina screens, so that is why my code didn't work. Once I replaced the retina logo as well everything worked as intended.